# Tem como usar uma mesma consulta e definir dois "ORDER BY" diferente?

Tags: php, mysql, query

Uso o seguinte trecho para uma consultado ao banco de dados

```
$cs1 = $pdo->query("SELECT TITULO, URL, IMAGEM , TEMPO FROM post ORDER BY CLIQUES DESC LIMIT 5")->fetchAll();
```

Gostaria então de explorar mais essa consulta com o intuito de usar menos memoria possível.

É o seguinte, na *home page* do site estou usando duas consultas distintas

```
$cs1 = $pdo->query("SELECT TITULO, URL, IMAGEM , TEMPO FROM post ORDER BY CLIQUES DESC LIMIT 5")->fetchAll();

$cs2 = $pdo->query("SELECT TITULO, URL, IMAGEM , TEMPO FROM post ORDER BY VOTOS DESC LIMIT 5")->fetchAll();
```

Como pode se ver a unica coisa que muda entre as consultas é a coluna citada no `ORDER BY`, onde em um a coluna citada do `ORDER BY` é `CLIQUES` e na outra `VOTOS`.

Na minha visão isso é um desperdício de recursos, já que ambas as consultadas são exibidas na mesma pagina. Existe então alguma maneira de fazer uma unica consulta porem determinar diferentes colunas no `ORDER BY` ? Algo tipo assim :

```
<?php 
    $colunas = ID, VOTOS, CLIQUES, CATEGORIA;

    $csu = $pdo->query("SELECT TITULO, URL, IMAGEM , TEMPO FROM post ORDER BY $colunas DESC LIMIT 5")->fetchAll();

?>
```

Ai tipo, a cada vez que atingir o limite de 5, pular pro próximo termo citado na variável `$colunas`

Comment: Porque não trazer os dados sem ordem definida e depois ordenar no `PHP`?

Comment: Como assim @Omni

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vejo duas soluções possíveis para esse problema:

1. Continuar usando duas consultas distintas e criar índices nas colunas `CLIQUES` e `VOTOS`. Ao usar índices o seu sistema gerenciador de banco de dados passará a trazer ambas as consultas mais rapidamente.
2. Trazer todo o *resultset* e ordenar com PHP. Dessa forma você não precisa criar os índices e pode ter sempre a mesma consulta.

Ordenação pela coluna `CLIQUES`:

```
usort($resultset, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['CLIQUES'] > $b['CLIQUES'];
});
```

Ordenação pela coluna `VOTOS`:

```
usort($resultset, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['VOTOS'] > $b['VOTOS'];
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Bem ivan veloso, quanto a questão dos recursos, fazer estas consultas separadamente, não será tão custoso, pois o MySQL trabalha com `Query Cache` e desta forma, antes das query's serem executadas, elas serão comparadas com os resultados armazenados no cache, e caso o resultado já exista não será necessário uma nova consulta. Para você verificar se esta funcionalidade está habilitada em seu MySQL você pode executar o comando:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'have_query_cache';
```

Quanto ao seu problema, caso você queira fazer um retorno apenas, para suas várias consultas com ordenações diferentes, você pode utilizar o recurso do `UNION ALL`. No entanto o retorno estará agrupado e você terá que tratá-lo no PHP. Sua query ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
(SELECT TITULO, URL, IMAGEM , TEMPO FROM post ORDER BY CLIQUES DESC LIMIT 5) as postcliques
UNION ALL
(SELECT TITULO, URL, IMAGEM , TEMPO FROM post ORDER BY VOTOS DESC LIMIT 5) as postvotos
```

Neste caso, se você possuir mais de 5 registros na tabela `post`, o retorno será de 10 registros, os 5 primeiros ordenados pelos cliques e os 5 últimos ordenados pelos votos.

Comment: Como executo o comando ao qual você se referiu?

Comment: Você pode executar, como uma query,  pelo terminal do MySQL ou por meio de um gerenciador, como o Phpmyadmin.